Different ways to dynamically make a new column in dplyr based on a variable
In practicing with the left hand side (LHS) declaration of column names in a non-standard evaluation context (a 'quasiquotation' context in tidy evaluation) I discovered a few things that are possible that I did not expect to be.
The code below speaks for itself I think. The [Why no error?] tags indicate where I think there should be errors, but there are none. Some clarification on why this is all possible would be very helpful, maybe along with the links to the documentation where all these uses are documented.
library(dplyr) 

varname1 <- sym("wow!") 
varname2 <- "blimey!" 
varname3 <- sym("crazy!") 
varname4 <- "wicked!"

tibble("eureka!" = 1:5) |> 
  mutate("eureka!" = 1) |>                # strings/character values on LHS are always possible (if you have something like ! in the name then the quotes are mandatory)
  mutate(!!varname1 := 2) |>              # from dplyr 0.7 we can use the walrus operator (:=) and !! for unquoting expressions on the LHS (specifically a symbol in this case) 
  mutate(!!varname2 := 3) |>              # [Why no error?] but actually just strings are also possible on LHS, as if it were a quasiquotated expression! 
  mutate("{varname2}_2" := 4) |>          # dplyr 1.0 makes this even more easy by allowing glue-like syntax on LHS, allowing for easy string injection 
  mutate("{varname1}&{varname2}" := 5) |> # [Why no error?] which means you can also inject what you want, even other quoted expressions apparently!
  mutate({{varname3}} := 6) |>            # dplyr 1.0 introduced curly-curly instead of !! for unquoting expressions 
  mutate("{{varname4}}" := 7) |>          # [Why no error?] however, like the glue-like LHS syntax supports expressions, curly-curly in turn happily supports strings!
  head()

Also, what's interesting is that the curly-curly ({{}}) operator apparently is not just 'syntactic sugar' for !!enquo(). It also works with symbols, strings and presumably anything. Maybe this works because in e.g. mutate call #6 it effectively runs enquo(sym("crazy!")), which is a quoted expression within  a quoted expression, and then evaluates it as many times it needs to obtain unquoted values only?
